# whether mysql has something like autoupdate

Tags: php, mysql, feature-selection

Database table schema.

```
CREATE TABLE `stackoverflow`.`automatic` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
    `values` VARCHAR( 200 ) NOT NULL ,
    `counts` BIGINT NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

now i want to update counts everytime data is updated automatically in mysql without hitting database.

I mean i know i can select that row and get old value and then increament it by one but my concern is that whether there's any way that mysql handle such things.

I didn't tried any code.
I just wanted to know from experts out there if they know anything about it.
As i am running on deadline i don't wanna use lengthy approach and i thought it would be cool if mysql already has something that could help me now.

Thanks.

Comment: You could use a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) for this purpose

Comment: @ppeterka can trigger update table field..?

Comment: Would I suggest it if it couldn't? Please read the documentation in the link in my previous comment. And Google is full of great examples.

Comment: Create two trigger. One for `delete` and one for `insert`.

Comment: You could, but you might be better of showing what problem you are trying to find a solution to: there might be better ways to get that number without saving it. For instance, if 'what' is updated? The row values? what is in there? that sounds like a field that might be more fields in a separate table for instance.

Comment: You can try on duplicate key update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in your update query itself

```
UPDATE `stackoverflow`.`automatic` set values='xyz', counts=(counts+1) where id=1;
```